# squid as http proxy configuration

Tags: squid, proxy-server

I am trying to use Squid as http proxy (proxy all requests from 88.99.219.124 using 85.10.219.144/29 subnet).

```
$ cat /etc/squid3/squid.conf    
acl client src 88.99.219.124
acl proxy dst 85.10.219.144/29
http_access allow client proxy
http_access deny all
http_port 3129

$ tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log
1543865940.128      0 88.99.219.124 TCP_DENIED/403 3486 CONNECT google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1543865940.138      0 88.99.219.124 TCP_DENIED/403 3486 CONNECT google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1543865940.147      0 88.99.219.124 TCP_DENIED/403 3486 CONNECT google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1543865940.156      0 88.99.219.124 TCP_DENIED/403 3486 CONNECT google.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Whats wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

Squid config:

```
$ cat /etc/squid3/squid.conf
acl client src 88.99.219.124
http_access allow client
http_access deny all
http_port 3129
debug_options ALL,1
```

---

To allow your server to use 85.10.219.144/29 subnet, add ip adresses from subnet to network interfaces.

Use [subnet calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=85.10.219.144&mask1=29) to find min & max ip in subnet range.

Network interfaces:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
...

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  x.x.x.x
        netmask  x.x.x.x
        gateway  x.x.x.x
        bridge-ports __network_interface_name__
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr0:0
iface vmbr0:0 inet static
        address 85.10.219.145
        netmask 255.255.255.248
auto vmbr0:1
iface vmbr0:1 inet static
        address 85.10.219.146
        netmask 255.255.255.248
auto vmbr0:2
iface vmbr0:2 inet static
        address 85.10.219.147
        netmask 255.255.255.248
auto vmbr0:3
iface vmbr0:3 inet static
        address 85.10.219.148
        netmask 255.255.255.248
auto vmbr0:4
iface vmbr0:4 inet static
        address 85.10.219.149
        netmask 255.255.255.248
auto vmbr0:5
iface vmbr0:5 inet static
        address 85.10.219.150
        netmask 255.255.255.248
```

---

And now when we try to use our proxy, it works!

```
$ curl -x http://85.10.219.150:3129 -L http://google.com
```

In log file:

```
$ cat /var/log/squid/access.log
1544717769.941     58 _your_ip_ TCP_MISS/200 13234 GET http://www.google.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/2a00:1450:4001:809::2004 text/html
```